# Pythonic way to reference an object in another class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to figure the best way to connect classes. Specifically, I want to know whether it is Pythonic to reference an object when creating a class.

So here are two examples that produce the same outcome:

Example 1

```
class A:
    def __init__(self,content):
        self.content = content

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.content = a.content

a = A('test')
b = B()
print(b.content)
```

Example 2

```
class A:
    def __init__(self,content):
        self.content = content

class B:
    def __init__(self,other_object):
        self.content = other_object.content

a = A('test')
b = B(a)
print(b.content)
```

In example 1 the object a is being used inside of the class. In example 2 that object is passed in as argument.

I get that example 2 is the better option because it is more deliberate, but would example 1 still be good practice?

Comment: That depends... do you always only need exactly one instance of `A` and under the global name `a`? If not, go for Example2.

Answer (score 1):

The two are implementing two fundamentally different functionalities:

- in the first approach you do not expose the object to work upon and rely  on some global name to be defined.
- in the second you explicitly ask for an object to use, which makes `class B` more self-contained.

Generally speaking, code that rely on global non-built-in names is considered bad practice.

But there are situations were this is acceptable.
For example, if `a` is holding an expensive computation that you do not really want to recompute each time (and even then, you could use memoization instead), then using a global name may be acceptable, but should be clearly documented.

Answer (score 0):

The first code is in my mind not good practice. Because `a` is initialized below the definition of `B`. So it is very counter intuitive to read.

The best solution depends on what the underlying logic is. Example 1 would be relevant if the class `A` is a singleton, e.g a database. But the initialization of `a` should be above `B` in my opinion.

If you always pass the same instance then it make sense to "hardcode" the attribute in the class otherwise I would use Example 2.